# How to derive $p(y = k | x)$ for a class-conditional gaussian bayes model?

Tags: machine-learning, normal-distribution, naive-bayes

If we have a Gaussian model with diagonal covariance matrices and shared
variances, how do we expand the equation? We have class labels y = (1, 2...,K) and a vector of D features x = (x1, x2, xD).

[image]

I know that given the Bayes rule:

$P(y=k|x,\mu,\sigma) = \dfrac{P(x|y = k,\mu,\sigma)P(y=k|\mu, \sigma)}{P(x|\mu, \sigma)}$

And using total probabilities:

$P(y=k|x,\mu,\sigma) = \dfrac{P(x|y = k,\mu,\sigma)P(y=k|\mu, \sigma)}{\sum_{i=1}^K P(x|y=y_i, \mu, \sigma)P(y = y_i | \mu,\sigma)}$

If we assume $P(y=k) = \alpha_k \forall k \in y$ then we can write it as:

$P(y=k|x,\mu,\sigma) = \dfrac{P(x|y = k,\mu,\sigma)\alpha_k}{\sum_1^K P(x|y=y_i, \mu, \sigma)\alpha_i}$

I could replace the individual elements with the initial equation, but I really do not know how I can simplify them in order to reach a simpler form.

Any advice? I found the process for only 2 classes here: https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jordan/courses/281A-fall04/lectures/lec-9-30.pdf

But it doesn't generalize well.